# Count days between two dates in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Today I am counting days between two dates in yii2. One date is on column of database. Database column is due_date. The other date is current date.

Here is the code for what I done so far in yii2 :

```
$abc=Yii::$app->db->createCommand('select * from lib_chekout where patron_id=:patron_id   AND is_checkedin=0')
   ->bindValue(':patron_id',$patron_id)
   ->queryAll();


$datetime1 =  $abc[0]['due_date'];
$datetime2 =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

print_r($interval);
exit;
```

> My due_date is no $abc array . Now how can I count the dates ?

For reference due_date has date `2011-08-13 00:00:00`. And today date is `2016-12-13`.

How can I do it ?

Comment: use date_diff($date1,$date2);

Comment: got an error ::   PHP Warning 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given'

Comment: $date1 and $date2 must be in date format use $date1=strtotime($date1); $date2=strtotime($date2);

Answer (score 3):

as @kashif said you can use `date_diff` function. first you need to convert you date to DateTimeInterface then pass it to `date_diff`.

```
//PARA: Date Should In YYYY-MM-DD Format
//RESULT FORMAT:
// '%y Year %m Month %d Day %h Hours %i Minute %s Seconds'        =>  1 Year 3 Month 14 Day 11 Hours 49 Minute 36 Seconds
// '%y Year %m Month %d Day'                                    =>  1 Year 3 Month 14 Days
// '%m Month %d Day'                                            =>  3 Month 14 Day
// '%d Day %h Hours'                                            =>  14 Day 11 Hours
// '%d Day'                                                        =>  14 Days
// '%h Hours %i Minute %s Seconds'                                =>  11 Hours 49 Minute 36 Seconds
// '%i Minute %s Seconds'                                        =>  49 Minute 36 Seconds
// '%h Hours                                                    =>  11 Hours
// '%a Days                                                        =>  468 Days
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function dateDifference($date_1 , $date_2 , $differenceFormat = '%a' )
{
    $datetime1 = date_create($date_1);
    $datetime2 = date_create($date_2);

    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

    return $interval->format($differenceFormat);

}
```

from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php)

Answer (score 1):

DateTime::diff -- DateTimeImmutable::diff -- DateTimeInterface::diff -- date_diff — Returns the difference between two DateTime objects

You must convert your date string into datetime object

```
$abc = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('select * from lib_chekout where patron_id=:patron_id   AND is_checkedin=0')
        ->bindValue(':patron_id',$patron_id)
        ->queryAll();


$datetime1 =  new Datetime($abc[0]['due_date']);
$datetime2 =  new Datetime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2)->days;


print_r($interval);
exit;
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/696177)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.
$datetime1 and $datetime2 should be DateTime object.

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2011-08-13 00:00:00');
//$datetime1 = new DateTime($abc[0]['due_date']);
$datetime2 = new DateTIme('Now');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

print_r($interval->format('%R%a'));
```